# Is my justification right in evaluating $\sum_{i=1}^{10}1$?

Tags: calculus, summation

Suppose we want to evaluate summation $\sum_{i=1}^{10}1$

For example If we have $S=\sum_{i=1}^{10} a_i$ , obviously we have $S=a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_{10}$. in the case$\sum_{i=1}^{10}1$ in fact we have that $a_i=1$. hence for each $i$ we get $1$ and after adding them together we get $10$.

Is my justification right? and is there something more to learn about these kind of summation where we have constant as the expression next to the sigma?

Comment: What you’ve done is correct. When the summand is a constant $k$, the sum is simply $k$ times the number of terms.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : Thank you sir!

Comment: You’re welcome!